# Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: (wrong name

Tags: java, exception

i want to execute java that is in lexing folder. the error is wrong name
[image: this is the error]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It "sounds" like `Lexing` doesn't belong to the `package` `lexing`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer but it is in the lexing folder, based on the manual given by lecturer it said that if the compilation successful then lexing.class will be generated and it has been generated

Comment: Does `Lexing` have a [`package` declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer dont know, just following the manual

Comment: @MadProgrammer ive uplloaded screenshot of the code

Comment: add `package lexing;` to the start of the file

Comment: @MadProgrammer before import?

Comment: Yep, ask explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer still wrong name :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the lexing folder to your classpath and then run Lexing class.

Example -

```
java -classpath lexing Lexing
```

---

Or you can also add `package lexing;` in your java file (normally put as the first statement) to indicate that `Lexing` class belongs to lexing package and then you would be able to run using the path -

```
java lexing.Lexing
```

Comment: ive added the package lexing; but its still does not work

Comment: Don't do the package one, do the classpath one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot of your code, you need to add the package deceleration `lexing` to the start of your source file.  See [Creating and Using Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html) for more details

So using...

```
package lexing;

public class Lexing {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

I placed it in the `lexing` directory (calling `Lexing.java`).

Then, at the command line (in the directory containing the `lexing` directory), I typed:

```
javac lexing\*.java
```

Followed by

```
java lexing.Lexing
```

Which output

```
Hello world
```

Having said all that, I would highly recommend making use of a suitable IDE